# Adding svg rectangles to checkboxes dynamically

Tags: javascript, checkbox, svg, d3.js

I'm trying to add a coloured rectangle on the left of each checkbox of a list, which are created automatically by d3.js with this code:

```
d3.selectAll("#checkbox")
.selectAll("label")
.data(dataset, function (d) { return d.Grazie; })
.enter()
.append("div")
.attr("id", function (d) { return d.Grazie; })
.append("label")
.attr("class", "label")
.attr("id", function (d) { return d.Grazie; })
.text(function (d) { return d.Grazie; })
.append("input")
.attr({
    type: "checkbox",
    class: "Grazie",
    name: "mode",
    value: function (d, i) { return d.Grazie; }
})
.attr("id", function (d, i) { return d.Grazie; })
.attr("x", margin)
.attr("y", margin)
.attr("selected", null);
```

I tried appending an svg and then a rectangle after this process, but what I get is that the rectangle is placed after the text and the checkbox, with this code:

```
d3.select("#checkbox")
.select("#Sans")
.append("svg")
.attr("width", 8 + "px")
.attr("height", 8 +  "px")
.append("rect")
.attr("fill", function (d) { 
    if (d.Grazie == "Sans") { return "#386cb0"; } 
    else { return "#f0027f"}})
.attr("x", 0)
.attr("y", 0)
.attr("width", 8 + "px")
.attr("height", 8 + "px");
```

The order I'd like to have is:
Rectangle - text - checkbox 
I guess that the code for the rectangle could be integrated while creating the checkbox, but wasn't able to make it work. Any help is really appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should break things up like this:

```
var entries = d3.select("#checkbox") // select is more appropriate than selectAll
  .selectAll("div.list-entry")
  .data(dataset, function (d) { return d.Grazie; })

var newEntries = entries.enter() // newEntries holds the result of .enter()
  .append("div")
  .attr("id", function (d) { return d.Grazie; })
  .attr("class", "list-entry")

newEntries // now you can append various stuff into each div in newEntries 
  .append("label")
  .attr("class", "label")
  .attr("id", function (d) { return d.Grazie; })
  .text(function (d) { return d.Grazie; })

newEntries
  .append("input")
  .attr({
      type: "checkbox",
      class: "Grazie",
      name: "mode",
      value: function (d, i) { return d.Grazie; }
  })
  .attr("id", function (d, i) { return d.Grazie; })
  .attr("x", margin)
  .attr("y", margin)
  .attr("selected", null);
```

Then you can insert the rectangle creation code right before the label creation code (following the same pattern used for label and input creation).

But... is there a reason why you're using and `<svg>` and a `<rect>` to make a simple rectangle? That's complicated. Why not just use a plain old `<div>` with css width, height, background-color and `display:inline-block` or `float:left`?

Comment: I simply didn't think of using a div for the color! thanks for the answer I'll try it out in a few!

Comment: sorry to bother you again but if i add divs instead of rectangles it will add the labels and checkboxes inside those two little divs! I am surely missing something here

Comment: Cool... Glad that worked. Unrelated: Nice dataviz designs btw.